# Can a single react application be served at multiple different URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, proxy

I have a React application deployed as an Azure web app. I would like to deploy a single application and have it be available at different URLs/subdomains. For example,

`customer1.mydomain.com`
`customer2.mydomain.com`

And I would like to detect that URL in the code to change branding. Is this possible with a standard React application in an Azure web app?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for React multi-tenancy architecture (easily searchable).

Comment: The app is already multi-tenant. I just need to solve the domain problem which I think might be as simple as a CNAME after looking around some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Azure Application gateway with multi-site listeners to host your 2 different hostnames `customer1.mydomain.com`  `customer2.mydomain.com` in your react app like below:-

Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal) to create Application gateway with multiple site listeners.

[image]

[image]

Now add your app service in the back end pool with 2 backend pools one for customer1.mydomain.com and another one for customer2.mydomain.com like below:-

[image]

[image]

Added 2 back end pools for customer1 and customer2 like below:-

[image]

Now, Go to Configuration > And Create a Routing rule with customer1 domain url like below:-

[image]

In the Backend targets select your customer1 backend pool that we created earlier like below:-

[image]

**Backend Targets:-**

[image]

[image]

Now click on Add and go back to the Add Routing setting and add the same settings for customer2 site like below:-

[image]

[image]

Click on Add and 2 of your sites will be added in the routing rule like below:-

[image]

Create Application Gateway like below:-

[image]

You can also make use of the code snippet below to detect the URL's :-

```js
const  hostname  =  window.location.hostname;

  

if (hostname  ===  'customer1.mydomain.com') {

// Change branding for customer1

} else  if (hostname  ===  'customer2.mydomain.com') {

// Change branding for customer2

} else {

// Default branding

}
```

You can register your custom domains in Azure App service by referring this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-external#create-a-cname-record-in-azure-static-web-apps) here:-

And you can add your Custom domain for customer1 and customer2 and add the CNAME and TXT record with your Domain registrar to validate the domain with app service like below:-

[image]