# 301 Redirect - Two Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I have an application running on **old-example-app.azurewebsites.net**. I want to setup a redirect from that application to another one in Azure that is **new-example-app.azurewebsites.net**. I want to accomplish this without having to make a code change and redeployment because I don't have deployment slots and my old-example-app has a lot of active users. Is there any setting I can enable or modify on the web app settings in Azure or am I stuck making a new deployment?

Comment: Can you add the image of any configuration you have made? Or any networking settings that is enabled for both the apps? Also, Refer my SO thread answer here- You can make use of Application gateway -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256154/can-a-single-react-application-be-served-at-multiple-different-urls/76260549#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Azure Application Gateway with Multi-site listener to route 2 URL's between your old azure web app and new azure web app.

[image]

[image]

In your backend pool, **Add 2 backend pools 1 for** **old-example-app.azurewebsites.net** **App and 2nd for** **new-example-app.azurewebsites.net** like below:-

**My App1:-**

[image]

**My App2:-**

[image]

[image]

Now, Create a routing rule to route the URL's for both the  Backend targets like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Refer my [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256154/can-a-single-react-application-be-served-at-multiple-different-urls/76260549#) for more details.